# Log4j2 - One app, multiples logs and levels

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

I have one application and more than one customer, I would like to separate the logs by customerId (java variable), also create different types of level level hierarchy.

For example:

/logs/customer1/admin.txt

/logs/customer1/support.txt

/logs/customer2/admin.txt

/logs/customer2/support.txt

I could separate by "levels" this way:
log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="WARN">
    <properties>
    <property name="appName">App</property>
    <property name="pattern">%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${appName} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</property>

    </properties>

    <appenders>
     <File name="adm" fileName="c:\logs\adm.txt" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
    </File>
    <File name="support" fileName="c:\logs\support.txt" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
    </File>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <Logger name="adm" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="adm" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="support" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="adm" />
            <AppenderRef ref="support" />
        </Logger>
        <root level="ERROR">
            <appender-ref ref="support" />
            <appender-ref ref="adm" />
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

and in the java:

```
static final Logger adm = LogManager.getLogger("adm");
static final Logger support= LogManager.getLogger("support");
```

with this configuration when I use "support.info"... the log goes to the both files. and It is perfect. but I couldn't separate by customerID

I'm doing it correctly? 
How can I separate by customerId(java variable)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate logs by using the RoutingAppender. Basically, you place the customer id in the ThreadContext and then have the RoutingAppender create a FileAppender that writes to a file location based on a pattern. This also has the advantage that the customer id can be included in every log record and your application can also retrieve it from there instead of requiring that it be passed everywhere as a parameter.

See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender for an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Each appender I replaced for:

```
    <Routing name="sadm">
        <Routes pattern="${ctx:customerId}">
            <Route>
                <File name="sadm" fileName="${path}\${ctx:customerId}\sadm.txt"
                    append="true">
                    <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
                </File>
            </Route>
            <Route ref="sadm_commom" key="${ctx:customerId}" />
        </Routes>
    </Routing>
```

and created a new appender named: sadm_commom

```
            <Route ref="sadm_commom" key="${ctx:customerId}" />
```

in case the customerID is null.

Comment: Are you saying that the RoutingAppender is working for you or is this a question?